# What to do with Unicode non-awareness in PHP < 6?

Tags: php, unicode, function

I'm working on a project which needs to be Unicode aware. PHP provides bunch of useful functions like str_count_words() to calculate the number of words in some input, but they won't work against UTF-8 data in PHP < 6 which is a shame. The same applies to strlen(), strrev(), etc.

What should I do about this? PHP 6 is still not even out yet so I can't require people to have it to use my software...

Should I just write a wrapper library for string functions that will either use PHP 6's functions or my own in case the version is below 6?

Comment: Does it have to be PHP? If Unicode support is a central concern, PHP5 may not be the best choice of platform.

Comment: It's a web application that has to work on as many platforms and servers as possible. It has to support Postgres, MySQL, SQL Server and Oracle RDBMS. It has to have XML parsing support and there are tons of other requirements and frankly PHP seems to make most sense.

Comment: Other modern scripting languages can certainly do XML and databases fine whilst also natively supporting Unicode strings. eg. Python, ASP.NET, the various scripting possibilities for Java. Whilst PHP support is the most widespread on cheapo shared hosting, that's only going to be PHP5 for quite a while yet, and Unicode support in PHP5 is highly substandard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [multibyte string comparison](http://www.php.net/mb%5Fstring) functions.

Another good idea might be looking at how others do it, especially well-established and matured systems like Wordpress and Drupal. As far as I am aware, they all have own wrappers around multibyte functions.

Additional possibly interesting resources:

- [PHP UTF-8 cheatsheet](http://developer.loftdigital.com/blog/php-utf-8-cheatsheet)
- [UTF-8: The secret of character encoding](http://htmlpurifier.org/docs/enduser-utf8.html)

Answer (score 3):

For multi-byte strings functions, you should check [Multibyte String Functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php)

For example, there is a [`mb_strlen`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strlen.php) function -- equivalent of `strlen`, but which works with UTF-8

Unfortunatly, there are only a few of those functions, and all `str*` don't necessarily have an `mb_str*` equivalent... Still, it is definitly possible to create a websiste that's 100% UTF-8 in PHP 5.x

Answer (score 1):

**I've created a wrapper class for this in PHP 5 (IMO this is the only reliable way to go), here are some my implementations of the functions you mentioned:**

```
function iki_String_str_word_count($string, $format = 0, $search = null)
{
    $result = iki()->Regex->Match_All($string, '[\p{L}\p{Mn}\p{Pd}\'\x{2019}' . iki()->Regex->Quote($search) . ']+', 0, 'u');

    if ($format == 0)
    {
        return count($result);
    }

    return $result;
}

function iki_String_strlen($string)
{
    return strlen(utf8_decode($string));
}
```

There is also an [open-source project @ SourceForge called PHP UTF-8](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phputf8/) that implements a lot of the `str_*` family of functions. The [Kohana PHP Framework](http://kohanaphp.com/) also claims to be 100% UTF-8 compatible.

Comment: PS: Forgive my specific methods, but I'm in a hurry and can't translate the code right now. Hopefully it'll be just enough to pass the message.

Answer (score 0):

As you suggest, you could create a wrapper library until PHP 6 becomes a standard install. (This is years away bearing in mind the speed of ISP take-up for PHP 5.

The [mb_string functions](http://www.php.net/mb_string) way well prove to be sufficient in the meantime.